# casperjs: import json and cycle export result json

Tags: json, database, csv, casperjs

I need import some links in casperjs and export result html in json or whatever, but if I have 1milion link in one file I need something automatic, like a cycle for call each link from json(example) then extract html with casperjs, then write in file json or whatever. This is my script but write in file and not take links in some file db, json or csv. How I can modify this script for my needs?:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: true,
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        cookiesEnabled: true
    }

});

var fs = require('fs');
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;

casper.start().thenOpen("LINK_LOGIN", function() {
    console.log("Link opened...");
    });
casper.then(
    function() {
        casper.echo("clicking..");
        casper.click(x("/html/body/div[@id='whais']/ul[@id='undest']/li[@id='login-you']/a"));
    });

casper.then(function(){
    console.log("Login...");
    this.sendKeys('input[id="login"]', 'USER');
    this.sendKeys('input[id="password"]', 'PASSWORD');
    casper.echo("click");
    casper.click('input[type="submit"][name="form"]');  
    this.evaluate(function(){
        document.getElementById("button-send").click();
    });

});

casper.thenOpen("OTHER_LINK_SAME_DOMAIN", function() {    
    console.log("page loading...");
    console.log("...write html");
    var html = this.getHTML();
    var f = fs.open('my.html', 'w');
    f.write(html);
    f.close();

}).waitForText("how are you?", function() {
    this.echo('Found the answer.');
},
function() {
    this.echo('not found answer, time out!');
},60000
);

casper.run();
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: please take a look at my answer... If you still have questions, please feel free to leave a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 1 milion link in one files.

First you should read the content of that file. Take a look at [fs.read](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/read.html).

> I need something automatic, like a cycle for call each link from json(example) then extract html with casperjs then write in file json or whatever.

Use a loop to open every url, then save it. A example code:

```
var url_list = [...]// contains the url from the local file

casper.start()
var index = 0;
casper.then(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < url_list.length; i++) {
            casper.thenOpen(url_list[i], function () {
                fs.write(index + '.html', this.getHTML(), 'w')
                index ++
            })
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your good answer, and sorry if I see just right now...Thank you again!!!